# Migrating Mail Data beetween Datacenters - Looking for Ideas

Tags: windows, storage, migration, ntfs

We already managed to migrate Hyper-V VMs (more than 70 TiB) by 3rd Party Backup Softwares with 10 minutes downtimes. However there is that one dirty job to handle; 4 TiB of Mail Data which provisioned by 8 TiB LUN. Mail Server VM access this LUN by Virtual FC Adapter (vSAN).

What i plan to do is something like below. Once the Filesystem synchronization done, migrate VM via replication, apply Virtual FC settings and done.

[image: Layout of what i meant to do]

But before applying below plan, i would like to consult to the community. I wish to minimalize down-time of mail service (Product is MailEnable). Also i have 3 weeks to solve this issue. Last resort is 8 hour downtime on weekend-midnight.

Also i would be approciate for any advice regarding rsync like tools for Windows Environments. I found this one : [SyncThing (OpenSource)](https://syncthing.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Use a migration tool like [Zerto](https://www.zerto.com/simplify/data-center-consolidation-and-mergers/) for this process to minimize potential downtime.

Comment: It would be perfect if my company could aford zerto :)

Comment: There are special pricing options for one-time moves. You could also use a free trial for 14 days and 5 VMs.